# How to read a parametrized List from file by using Gson?

Tags: java, generics, gson, generic-list, typetoken

I am trying to write a convenient method to read a List of objects from different files. Right now I have this one:

```
public <T> List<T> parseList(String file) {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(loader.getResourceAsStream(file))) {

        return gson.fromJson(gson.newJsonReader(reader), new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());

    } catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Cannot read json file "+ file, e);
        throw new JBCCannotReadFileException(e);
    }
}
```

When I try to use this method like:

```
List<MyObject> myList = parseList(filtPath);
```

It returns `List<LinkedTreeMap<...>>`. The strange thing also is that it successfully assigns that value to `List<MyObject>` and after I try to access `myList` it throws an exception that `LinkedTreeMap` cannot be converted into `MyObject`.

When I use `new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyObject>>(){}.getType()` instead of `new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType()` it works as expected but when the type is generic (`T`) it works really strange. Is there a way to fix the above method?